# Implement Android Search Activity, SearchManager cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: android, search, android-activity, searchmanager

I am trying to create a searchable activity however when I get to this point, I have the red squiggly under SearchManager (in Eclipse) and it says:

```
SearchManager cannot be resolved to a variable
```

It gives me 8 quick fixes but none if them are helpful.  Am I missing something easy?  I am building against 4.0, my minSDK is 7 and targetSDK is 13.  T

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That comes under the Google APIs section. Change the build target to Google APIs under Project Properties > Android.

[image: Build Target]